# WebStorm - Comment out lines shortcut doesn't work

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, shortcut

I'm new to WebStorm and would like to know the shortcut to comment out the current line (the cursor is in).

I'm on a Mac and found the Shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, since I'm on a german Mac-Keyboard this means I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>(I normally need to type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> to get a  `/`).

Sadly this shortcut doesn't work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue, see [IDEA-63779](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779) and linked tickets. This is the JDK limitation (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022079), we are working on possible workarounds.

setting  `ide.non.english.keyboard.layout.fix=true` per suggestion in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779#comment=27-841611 sometimes helps...